# jQuery UI Autocomplete widget: Edit search term before perform search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I use an autocomplete widget on a text input (***#MapSearchName***). The source is a simple array of strings (***MapListNames***). I need to modify the search term, before show autocomplete results.

In my case the ***MapListNames*** array contents strings in cyrillic and it works when user searches in cyrillic. I want autocomplete to suggest search results when a user searches in latin too. I wrote a ***Met2Kir()*** function which converts a latin string to a cyrillic one.

I found that this should be done by using the request/response function, but in the Autocomplete documentation that is not described particularly clear and I can not guess what should be the right way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
    $( "#MapSearchName" ).autocomplete({
    // source: MapListNames,
    delay: 0,
    autoFocus: true,

    source: function( request, response ) {
      var term = Met2Kir(request.term);
      response(  MapListNames, function( item ){
          return term;
      } );
    }   

});
```

I need some help with the **source:** part, so that any user input to be processed by the Met2Kir() function before it is sent for search.

The whole situation can be found here: [Lyaskovets Citymap](http://lyaskovets.net/d2_ref2_citymap.php) (it's in bulgarian, but the ***#MapSearchName*** is right below the map)

The JS code is at the end of [citymap.js file](http://lyaskovets.net/scripts/citymap.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by filtering the results into a new Array and sending them back to `response()`. For example:

```
$("#MapSearchName").autocomplete({
  delay: 0,
  autoFocus: true,
  source: function( request, response ) {
    var term = Met2Kir(request.term);
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(MapListNames, term);
    response(results);
  }
});
```